# Eager loading of virtual link being lost when using linq 'select new ...'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, eager-loading

I have a problem with my virtual link. Entity framework doesn't seem to eager load in cases where the UserID = 0. I'm using Entity Framework 6 .NET Framework 4.5.2 and VS2013

```
    public class Booking
    {
       [Key]
       public int Booking_ID { get; set; }
       public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
       public DateTime StartDate_DT { get; set; }
       public DateTime BookingDate_DT { get; set; }
       public int UserID { get; set; }
       public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }     
    }
```

This does not include any record from the Booking table with a UserID of 0:

```
     var list = (from booking in _db.Booking
                 where booking.Customer_ID == customerId
                 orderby booking.StartDate_DT, booking.BookingDate_DT
                 select new CustomerBookingLine
                 {
                    BookingId = b.Booking_ID,
                    StartDate = b.StartDate_DT,     
                    BookingDate = b.BookingDate_DT, 
                    UserName = b.UserProfile != null ?   b.UserProfile.UserName : null
                  }).ToList();
    return list;
```

This does return the booking records including eager-loaded user profile records

```
    var list = (from b in _db.Booking
                where b.Customer_ID == customerId
                orderby booking.StartDate_DT, booking.BookingDate_DT
                select b).ToList();

         return (from b in bookingList
                 select new CustomerBookingLine
                 {
                    BookingId = b.Booking_ID,
                    StartDate = b.StartDate_DT,
                    BookingDate = b.BookingDate_DT,
                    UserName = b.UserProfile != null ?   b.UserProfile.UserName : null
                }).ToList();
```

I've tried using includes but the 2nd method is the only way I can get it to work. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It does not work only for user with ID = 0?

Comment: @MacakM - the first approach doesn't work - it doesn't bring back bookings that have a userId of 0. The 2nd approach does work - all bookings are returned for a customer regardless of userId being 0...  however I'm trying to understand why the first approach doesn't work.